# An option in my do-while to print out all 3 conditions

Tags: java

```
String xdd="";
        Scanner Lenijs = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
        System.out.println("Starting number a: ");
        int a = Lenijs.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ending number b: ");
        int b = Lenijs.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Choose 1.for a-b, 2. for all even and 3. for odd numbers.");
            int c = Lenijs.nextInt();
            if (c == 1) {
            do{
                System.out.println(a);
                a++;
            }while(a<=b);
        }
        if(c == 2) {
            if(a%2==0) {
                do{
       System.out.println(a);
                    a=a+2;
                }while(a<=b);
            }
            else {
                a++;
                do{
                    System.out.println(a);
                    a=a+2;
                }while(a<=b);
            }
        }
        if(c == 3) {
            if(a%2==0) {
                a++;
                do{
      System.out.println(a);
                    a=a+2;
                }while(a<=b);
            }
            else {
                do{
                    System.out.println(a);
                    a=a+2;
                }while(a<=b);
            }
            }
        System.out.println("Do you wish to continue? (Yes/No)");
        xdd=Lenijs.next();

        }while(xdd.equals("Yes"));   
    
    }

    }
```

How could I add a 4th option where the user can print out all 3, as of now you can individually select from 1-3 where u get for 1.just from a-b all numbers, 2.is a-b with only pairs and 3.is a-b only odd, but I wanted a 4th option where u could get them all together and is easy to read/overview. Is that possible to make or it won't look good/can't with my code?

Comment: Create an option, c == 4. Then do ``if (c == 1 || c == 4) { ... }`` (replace with c == 2 and c == 3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally a good practice to limit a method to doing just one thing.  So the method that decides which action to perform should not be performing the action - it passes responsibility to the appropriate method(s).  In this case, move each activity into a separate method and use a switch to invoke each as appropriate. The following illustrates the concept.

```
switch(c) {
  case 1:
    do1();
    break;
  case 2:
    do2();
    break;
  case 3:
    do3();
    break;
  case 4:
    do1();
    do2();
    do3();
    break;
  default:
    reportUnknownEntry(c);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, all of that worked except for the closing code which let's the user restart it `System.out.println("Do you wish to continue? (Yes/No)");
        xdd=Lenijs.next();

        }while(xdd.equals("Yes"));   `        it says that the code is unreachable, how could I put it so it's reachable?